# Side menu drawer is not showing up, instead screen is rendering blank

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to create a side drawer only for one screen hence am using react-native-side-drawer as per the documentation in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-side-drawer, however when I try to rerender it my screen is showing up blank as follows:
[image]

Below is my exact and complete code:

```
   import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      ScrollView,
      ActivityIndicator,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      StyleSheet,
      Image,
    } from 'react-native';
    
    import MenuDrawer from 'react-native-side-drawer';
    
    
    export default function HomeTabScreen(props) {
      const {navigation} = props;
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    
    
      // side drawer
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('useEffect - user', User);
        // console.log('useEffect - mSChildId', mSChildId);
    
        if (isValidObject(User) && isValidObject(mSChildId)) {
          console.log('useEffect true');
          console.log('useEffect true - user', User);
          if (loadApi == true) {
            getHomeTabMainAPI();
            setLoadApi(false);
            setSelectedChild(getChildFromUserChildrenList());
          }
        } else {
          console.log('useEffect false');
          if (!isValidObject(User) || !isValidObject(mSChildId)) {
            console.log(
              '!!!!!! Calling get user data !!!! Child Id  ',
              mSChildId,
              ' User Valid ',
              isValidObject(User),
            );
            getUserData();
          }
        }
      }, [User, mSChildId, loadApi]);
    
      
     
     
    
    
      const toggleOpen = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
      };
      const drawerContent = () => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              marginLeft: '80%',
            }}
            onPress={() => logoutHandler()}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000'}}>
              Log out
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      };
    
     
    
    
     
    
      return (
        <SafeAreaView
          style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          {loading ? (
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FE017E" />
            </View>
          ) : (
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  flex: 1,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                }}>
                <MenuDrawer
                  open={open}
                  drawerContent={drawerContent()}
                  drawerPercentage={45}
                  animationTime={250}
                  overlay={true}
                  opacity={0.4}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: '#fff',
                      padding: 10,
                      justifyContent: 'space-between',
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                    }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleOpen()}>
                      <Icon size={15} name="bars" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
    
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: '80%',
                      }}
                      onPress={() => logoutHandler()}>
                      <Text
                        style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000'}}>
                        Log out
                      </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                 <View>
renders more stuff here.....that should show up on the screen 
</View>
                </MenuDrawer>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          )}
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: 30,
        zIndex: 0,
      },
      animatedBox: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#38C8EC',
        padding: 10,
      },
      body: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F04812',
      },
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know where I have gone wrong.

P.S: I am getting all the data on my console, but not on the screen

Comment: I would suggest you to use react drawer navigation and then if you want to customise the drawer. You can easily do it using drawer content

Comment: I have a bottomtabnavigator inside stack navigator, creating drawer navigator again with all these navigators, are getting complicated also I want it only on one screen, so is there any other option? @akshaylalwani

Comment: I have proceeding uptil a certain extent, you could check out this link which is my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289751/react-native-side-drawer-not-closing , if possible please check through the code and help @akshaylalwani It would be a great help